# Is my idea for creating html parser from scratch going to work?

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

In order to practice my skills im going to write an html parser. The idea I have in mind:

- Define what I want to tokenize via regex.
- Accept some html as a string.
- Loop through html string.
- Save information about the token such as content and position as an object.
- If token has another token then that token is a child object of the parent token.
- Finish object graph.
- Create appropiate getters and setters.

Would you say this makes sense?

Comment: Should read famous answer [You can't parse HTML with regexl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: The [description of an HTML parser](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#parsing) in the HTML specification is character-based and uses state machines, so I would start by looking at that for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions aren't a good fit for heavy HTML parsing such as this; [regular expressions are a tool that is insufficiently sophisticated to understand the constructs employed by HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Your best bet would be to use a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) or a [tokeniser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)) based implementation.

You can also read more about parsing HTML5 in the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing).

Comment: How do I tokenize text though? I cant think of anything other than some simple regex or using split

Comment: I just need to define delimiters like white space